# how to block white spaces in urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

how to block whitespaces or %20

in my web site

and now i am using this code on .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z-]+)/([0-9]+).html$ filecat.php?LANGUAGE=$1&CITY=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

and its good on this here

```
http://localhost/amskn/filecat.php?LANGUAGE=ar&CITY=jahra-governorate&page=1
http://localhost/amskn/ar/jahra-governorate/1.html
```

the problem is when its contain space its work too

```
http://localhost/amskn/ar/jahra-governorate%20/1.html
```

how to block whitespaces or %20 in urls

Comment: `([a-z-]+)` can not match anything that contains a space to begin with. (And your rule could not match anything, unless you have that .htaccess inside your `amskn` sub folder.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is cause by generated url? you can using `str_replace` php function before you generate it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

`str_replace(' ', '', $url);`